# Getting a word "about:blank" in header section when I print a report though my web app from Chrome Browser Issue

Tags: issue-tracking

When I print a report through my web application from Google Chrome. I am getting a word "about:blank" in header section. I dont want to remove my footer section as it is display with proper data. I want to remove (about:blank) or replace only my header section when I print report from Chrome. Can any one provide me a solution for the same.

Thanks in advance